# CSS not showing up with ERB

Tags: css, ruby, dns, sinatra, erb

I've just hosted something on Heroku, and whenever I opened the app it worked just fine with the css being linked as such:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
```

The problem came when I added my custom domain, the css no longer worked.  When I view source and click on the href, it get a response "Not Found".  Nothing has changed, my css folder is still in my public folder in my apps directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried different paths for the `href`, like

```
href="../css/style.css"
```

or

```
href="css/style.css"
```